# Change Like Button

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, lumen

I'm working with Lumen, Vuejs and Axios. Users who are signed in can post something, and other users can like and comment on it. What I want to do is to make it obvious that someone liked the post. But I'm not able to switch the button after someone liked it.

This is my Vuejs Code:

```
  <button class="btn btn-light" @click="likes(item.id)"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></button>

  <button class="btn btn-light" @click="likes(item.id)"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button>
```

```
    likes(id){
      const axiosConfig = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
      };
      const postData = {
          posts_id: id,
          likes: true
       };
        axios.post('http://lumen.local/like', postData, axiosConfig)
        .then(response => {
          this.getPosts();
          })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          });
    },
```

And this is my lumen Code:

```
      $post_query = Posts::with('comments')
             ->with('comments.owner')
             ->with('likes.isLiked')
             ->withCount('likes')
             ->where('user_id', $user->id)
             ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
             ->limit($request->limit)
             ->get();
```

I tried to make another function where I can get the user_id of the logged in user, so I can change the button with vue-if

```
  public function checkLike(Request $request)
  {
    $user_name= $request->username;
    $user = User::where('username', $user_name)->first();

    $post_id = $request->posts_id;
    $post = Posts::find($post_id);

    $like = Likes::where('posts_id', $post_id)
                    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
                    ->get();

    if(count($like) == 0){
      return response()->json('no likes');
    } else{
      return response()->json($like);
    }

  }
```

It worked in postman, but I was not able to implement it in Vuejs, because I could not get the user_id without a v-for. So I thought I should get the user_id in the posts_query but I couldn't do it. 
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Just to have a clearer information, can you copy/paste the request responses you get from the back ? It might be quickly done with a few JS workarounds

Comment: comments: Array(1)
content: "thehehe"
created_at: (...)
id: 829
likes: Array(4)
likes_count: 4
updated_at: (...)
user_id: 217

This is what I get back from the post_query. I think I need the user_id of the one who liked it. The user_id above is from the one who posted it.

Comment: Okay thank you, but what I'd like to see is the content of your `likes` array. Does the array contain information about the users who liked the post ? If yes, and if it actually gives the id for each user, then you'll be able to tweak the VueJS code to display what you're looking for !

Comment: So my likes array looks like this: created_at: (...)
id: (...)
is_liked: (...)
likes: (...)
posts_id: (...)
updated_at: (...)
user_id: 220. And the user_id gives the id of the one who liked. But how can I make the code in Vuejs, to look for the authenticated user? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Okay now we're close to the goal ; if I understood your needs, you want to have a button that changes its look when the current user has liked it ? So basically, you get the `user_id` of the current user, and if you find that same `user_id` inside the button's `liked` array, then you make the button dark or disabled. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes thats what I want, but I was not able to get the user_id of the one who liked it without a v-for.

Comment: `v-for` is a really powerful feature so you should use it if you think you need it (as long as you do not execute needlessly repetitive things) ; I've posted my answer below based on the details you gave me, this might help you !

Answer (score 0):

Based on the details you gave me in the comments, I can suggest you to try this.
(I have not tested it yet so ther might be some syntax errors)

In your Vue script part :

```
data() {
  return {
    currentUserId: null,
    items: null,
  }
},

mounted() {
  this.getCurrentUserId()
  this.getPosts()
},        

methods: {
  getCurrentUserId() {
    // returns the ID of the current user
  },
  likes() {
    // your method
  },
  getPosts() {
    axios.get(MY_URL)
      .then (res => {
        const posts = res.data
        /* 
         *  creates a new array that contains each post + a boolean that indicates if 
         *  the current user has liked or not.
         */
        this.items = posts.map(post => ({
          ...post,
          liked: this.isPostLiked(post.likes)
        }))
      })
      .catch (err => {
        console.error(err)
      })      
  },
  /* 
   *  Not sure if your likes array is composed like this.
   *  This method looks for the currentUserId inside the 
   *  likes array passed as an argument. Returns true when
   *  it finds one, otherwise returns false.
   */
  isPostLiked(likesArray) {
    likesArray.forEach(like => {
      if (like.user_id === this.currentUserId) {
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }
},
```

Now we should obtain an array of objects that contains each post with its liked state.

Then you only have to loop through it with a `v-for` in your template:

```
<div v-if="items !== null" class="like-buttons">
  <button 
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
    :key="'item_' + index"
    class="btn btn-light"
    @click="likes(item.id)"
  >
    <i v-if="item.liked === true" class="far fa-heart" />
    <i v-else class="fas fa-heart" />
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's know a while since I posted the question, but I was not able to look at it. So i take a look, it isn't working for me. I also have a getPosts method, and I think maybe that's the problem. And I also did not understand the method with the map.

Comment: Thats my get Posts method:     getPosts(){
      let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      this.axios.get(url"+this.$route.params.username,
      {
       headers: {
         Authorization: token
       }
      }).then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        });
    }